# Randomly sized chunking of a numpy array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to divide an index array in randomly sized chunks (taken from a limited range of possible sizes) which are also shuffled between each other. I tried the following I found [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4872/pythonic-split-list-into-n-random-chunks-of-roughly-equal-size) but it is focused on equally sized chunks.

```
a = np.arange(1, 100)

def chunk(xs, n): # to chunk the array xs in n parts
    ys = list(xs)
    random.shuffle(ys)
    size = len(ys) // n
    leftovers= ys[size*n:]
    for c, xtra in enumerate(leftovers):
        yield ys[c*size:(c+1)*size] + [ xtra ]
    for c in xrange(c+1,n):
        yield ys[c*size:(c+1)*size]
```

In other words, how could I change the above function to have a certain number of chunks (random number and shuffled between each other) with a variable size taken random from a range, e.g. `[5-10]`

Comment: Your question isn't complete yet.. What is the range? How is it calculated?

Comment: lets say the range of possible sizes is 5-10. It is not relevant but I will add it to the question

Comment: In that case you may or may not satisfy the n number of chunks constraint, right?

Comment: Yes exactly. The relevant variable is the limitation on the chunks' sizes which should be randomly picked in a specific range, e.g. [5-10]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This'll work:

```
from itertools import chain
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(1, 100)
def chunk(xs, nlow, nhigh, shuffle=True):
    xs = np.asarray(xs)
    if shuffle:
        # shuffle, if you want
        xs = xs.copy()
        np.random.shuffle(xs)

    # get at least enough random chunk sizes in the specified range, ie nlow <= n <= nhigh
    ns = np.random.randint(nlow, nhigh+1, size=xs.size//nlow)
    # add up the chunk sizes to get the indices at which we'll slice up the input array
    ixs = np.add.accumulate(ns)
    # truncate ixs so that its contents are all valid indices with respect to xs
    ixs = ixs[:np.searchsorted(ixs, xs.size)]

    # yield slices from the input array
    for start,end in zip(chain([None], ixs), chain(ixs, [None])):
        yield xs[start:end]

list(chunk(a, 5, 10))
```

Output:

```
[array([67, 79, 17, 62, 12, 37, 70, 24]),
 array([98, 48, 88, 59, 47]),
 array([52, 60, 89, 23, 43, 44]),
 array([ 7, 27, 33, 74, 49,  2]),
 array([ 6, 51, 40, 13, 56, 45]),
 array([31,  3, 55, 10, 11, 46,  9, 42, 34]),
 array([53, 22, 95, 41, 19, 32,  4, 69, 86]),
 array([93, 68, 57, 65, 92, 76, 28, 63, 64, 58]),
 array([91, 66, 18, 99, 21]),
 array([36, 83, 15, 78,  1, 81, 97, 84]),
 array([61, 71, 25, 94, 87, 20, 85, 38]),
 array([ 8, 96, 75, 30, 77, 14, 72, 29]),
 array([35, 90, 82, 73, 39,  5, 26, 50, 16]),
 array([80, 54])]
```

## edit

My original answer doesn't put a lower bound on the size of the final chunk, so sometimes it will be smaller than specified (though never larger). As far as I know there's no direct way of dealing with this. However, in general you can remove an unwanted region from a random distribution by just rejecting any samples that comes from that region. In other words, you can ensure that the last chunk is large enough by just throwing out any proposed chunks in which it is not:

```
def getIxs(xsize, nlow, nhigh):
    # get at least enough random chunk sizes in the specified range, ie nlow <= n <= nhigh
    ns = np.random.randint(nlow, nhigh+1, size=xsize//nlow)

    # add up the chunk sizes to get the indices at which we'll slice up the input array
    ixs = np.add.accumulate(ns)

    # truncate ixs so that its contents are all valid indices with respect to xs
    ixs = ixs[:np.searchsorted(ixs, xsize)]

    return ixs

def chunk(xs, nlow, nhigh):
    xs = np.asarray(xs)

    ixs = getIxs(xs.size, nlow, nhigh)

    # rerun getIxs until the size of the final chunk is large enough
    while (xs.size - ixs[-1]) < nlow:
        ixs = getIxs(xs.size, nlow, nhigh)

    # yield slices from the input array
    for start,end in zip(chain([None], ixs), chain(ixs, [None])):
        yield xs[start:end]
```

This approach should preserve the overall randomness of each of the chunk sizes.

Comment: Splendid! The option shuffle = False is exactly what I wanted. Thanks! :)

Comment: @Garini yeah, I wasn't sure if `shuffle` was something you intended or if was just cruft carried over in the copied code. So I made it optional

Comment: there is only a defect, I noted. The last division can break the size limit randomly. There is a way to avoid this?

Comment: @Garini By design (more or less) the final chunk can be smaller than the lower bound. There's no efficient way around this, but you can use a "rejection" based approach to get what you want. I've posted some related code above in an edit

Answer (score 0):

you can use `np.split(array,indices)`

```
import random
a = np.arange(100)
np.random.shuffle(a)
ind = sorted(random.sample(range(len(a)),k=np.random.randint(low=1,high=10)))
np.split(a,ind)



  [array([41, 19, 85, 51, 34]),
 array([71, 27]),
 array([36, 16, 18, 74, 43, 96, 45, 97, 54, 75, 89, 48, 33, 32, 63, 98,  5,
        80, 30, 17, 86, 14, 67]),
 array([ 9, 70, 84, 99, 39]),
 array([59, 20, 78, 61, 49, 37, 93]),
 array([ 1, 79, 81, 69, 40, 42, 29,  8,  3, 68, 87, 66,  4, 21, 91, 92, 31]),
 array([83, 15, 56,  2, 64, 95, 12,  0, 90, 77, 57, 60, 38, 76, 94, 22, 24,
         6, 46, 65, 50, 62, 28, 44, 73, 13, 26, 72,  7, 53, 82, 47, 58, 35,
        52, 25, 88, 11, 10, 55, 23])]
```

Comment: In my case, I wanted to keep the size of the split in a limited range without imposing the number of splits. Also, I needed to have ordered numbers in the splits.

Comment: In this case, k should also be a random number ,  but not sure, what do you mean by  ordered numbers in the splits? Do you want the splits to be sorted , even though  the original array is not sorted ?